# How to redirect next page after successfully login with flutter?

Tags: django, flutter, authentication, jwt

I create a simple login app with flutter. Backend is simple Jwt. After successfully login, Can not redirect to other page please help
This is login page code

```
            //login buttom
            SizedBox(
              width: 360,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 48.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    authController.loginUser();
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 41, 131),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 16,
                        bottom: 16,
                      )),
                  child: const Text(
                    'ログイン ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ), //end login buttom
            const SizedBox(
              height: 60,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is auth controller code

```
class AuthController {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  Future loginUser() async {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login/';

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "accept": "application/json",
          "access": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",
          "allow": "POST, OPTIONS",
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "email": emailController.text,
          "password": passwordController.text,
        }));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var loginArr = json.decode(response.body);
      print('Home');
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Nav()));
      // save this token in shared prefrences and make user logged in and navigate

      print(loginArr['token']);
    } else {}
  }
}
```

I try to fix this error please help me.how to navigate to other page after successfully login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 onPressed: () async {
             await  authController().loginUser().whenComplete(() => {
                      if (authController.isSuccess){
                          // Navigate to next page    
                        }
              },
```

change your onPressed from the login button

```
class AuthController { 
      TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
      bool isSuccess = false;
    
      Future loginUser() async {
        const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login/';
    
        var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
            headers: {
              "content-type": "application/json",
              "accept": "application/json",
              "access": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",
              "allow": "POST, OPTIONS",
            },
            body: jsonEncode({
              "email": emailController.text,
              "password": passwordController.text,
            }));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      

          isSuccess = true;
          var loginArr = json.decode(response.body);
          print('Home');
      
    
    
          print(loginArr['token']);
        } else {
          isSuccess = false;
        }
      }
}
```

You can set an success bool to know your api is success or not